# Convert object[] "list" from SQL query into string[] "test"

Tags: c#, arrays, string, object, converters

I wanna convert an object Array called "list" into a string Array called "test".
Attached the code.
The Problem is, the function is returning "System.Collections.Generic.Dic..." and not the strings in SQL database.
Thanks..

Code:

```
    public string[] ListMethod(string command)
    {
        MySqlCommand comm = new MySqlCommand(command, conn);
        MySqlDataReader commreader;
        commreader = comm.ExecuteReader();

        var list = new List<IDictionary<string, object>>();           

        while (commreader.Read())
        {
            var record = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            for (int i = 0; i < commreader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                var key = commreader.GetName(i);
                var value = commreader[i];
                record.Add(key, value);
            }

            list.Add(record);
        }
        string[] test = ((IEnumerable)list).Cast<object>().Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
        return test;
    }
```

Comment: What is your SQL query?

Comment: What strings do you want in your resulting array?  Currently your items are name/value pairs, and your values aren't all strings.  Do you want the names, do you want the values, if so, how do you want to deal with the values that aren't strings?

Comment: What are you trying to return? If you didn't want a dictionary, you could simply create a List<String> and add to it whatever you wanted.

Comment: My SQL query isn't necessary. The sql-query returns a list of strings (excatly usernames), 1 column and I wanna return this usernames in a string[] in c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets look at your LINQ Query:

```
string[] test = ((IEnumerable)list).Cast<object>().Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
```

What you are saying to the compiler here is:

Cast all objects in the list of dictionaries to object, and then execute to ToString() method of each object (which by default always prints the name of the class) and set it to an array (The cast do IEnumerable is redundant since List implements that interface anyway.

What you actually need to do is:

```
var test = list.Select(x => x.Values.ToString()).ToArray();
```

assuming all your values in the IDictionary are actually strings, this will fetch them for you.

Comment: Hey Yuval,
thanks for your reply, I've understood what you wanna tell me and replaced my "string[] test = ((IEnumarable........" with your "var test = list.Select...." this works also but it returns exactly the same as my Query. So I read also the Class name..

Comment: That means that the values the your are holding in your IDictionary<string, object> are not actually strings. Could you please tell me what that dictionary contains? and why is it a string to object and not string to string?